# Makefile.am commands to override library functions

Tags: c, makefile, packaging, autotools

I have an open source project that relies on another open source project (let's call that other project X).  Both are written in C.  I've had to hack pieces of X to get multi-threading to work.  This causes some issues when trying to package up the code for distribution.  To make things easier, I've just included the entirety of X within mine along with the few little hacks I've made.

I'd like to do something more sophisticated now in order to keep the improved functionality of X (it has frequent releases and mine does not) without having to repackage the whole project (with my hacks) within my project again each time that X has a release.

There are only 3 or 4 functions in that need to override.  I can follow what is going on in this [IBM Tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-glibc/index.html), but how can I modify my Makefile.am to generate the Makefile changes suggested in that article?  To summarize, the article suggests writing my own functions with the same signatures as the ones I want to override (in a file called libfuncs.c) and then add the following 'libs' target to the makefile:

```
all: libs setresgid-tester

libs: libfuncs.c
             gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libfuncs.so.1 -o libfuncs.so.1.0  libfuncs.c 
             ln -s libfuncs.so.1.0 libfuncs.so.1
             ln -s libfuncs.so.1 libfuncs.so

setresgid-tester: setresgid-tester.c
         gcc -o setresgid-tester setresgid-tester.c
```

All of that makes sense to me.  What I need to do, however, is to have this 'libs' target created for me with the autotools.  I have a Makefile.am works well right now.  How do I modify it to produce the desired results above?  It was difficult to find in the autotools documentation, but I may just not have known exactly what to look for.

I'm happy to provide more details if helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to send your patches to the upstream maintainer of the X library?

Comment: Not really.  My patch truly is a hack.  It serves the purposes of my application, but destroys some functionality in that library.